# Error while writing to file with multiprocessing

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing, file-writing

I am working on html parser, it uses Python multiprocessing Pool, because it runs through huge number of pages. The output from every page is saved to a separate CSV file. The problem is sometimes I get unexpected error and whole program crashes and I have errors handling almost everywhere - reading pages, parsing pages, even writing files. Moreover it looks like the script crashes after it finishes writing a batch of files, so it shouldn't be anything to crush on. Thus after whole day of debugging I am left clueless.

Error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programy\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "D:\Programy\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "D:\ppp\Python\parser\run.py", line 244, in media_process
    save_media_product(DIRECTORY, category, media_data)
  File "D:\ppp\Python\parser\manage_output.py", line 180, in save_media_product
    _file_manager(target_file, temp, temp2)
  File "D:\ppp\Python\store_parser\manage_output.py", line 214, in _file_manager
    file_to_write.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_to_write' referenced before assignment
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ppp\Python\store_parser\run.py", line 356, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Rzeczy Mariusza\Python\store_parser\run.py", line 318, in main
    process.map(media_process, batch)
  File "D:\Programy\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "D:\Programy\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_to_write' referenced before assignment
```

It look like, there is an error with variable assignment, but it is not:

```
try:
    file_to_write = open(target_file, 'w')
except OSError:
    message = 'OSError while writing file name - {}'.format(target_file)
    log_error(message)
except UnboundLocalError:
    message = 'UnboundLocalError while writing file name - {}'.format(target_file)
    log_error(message)
except Exception as e:
    message = 'Total failure "{}" while writing file name - {}'.format(e, target_file)
    log_error(message)
else:
    file_to_write.write(temp)
    file_to_write.write(temp2)
finally:
    file_to_write.close()
```

Line - `except Exception as e:`, does not help with anything, the whole thing still crashes. So far i have excluded only Out Of Memory scenario, because this script is designed to be handled on low spec VPS, but in testing stage I run it in environment with 8 GB of ram. So if You have any theories please share.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Python, but in every language that I know, equivalent code would crash in the `finally` block if the `open` call fails.

Comment: I do not know, but the `try except` is basically in its own function, so there is not possible to reference `file_to_write` before assignment.

Comment: It did not crash with `OSError while writing file name`, so it looks like when error is caught there is not problem. This is a clue, that the script crashes due to error which is not in any of those exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception really says what is happening.

This part is telling you obvious issue:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_to_write' referenced before assignment
```

Even you have `try/except` blocks that catches various exceptions, `else/finally` doesn't.

More specifically in `finally` block you reference variable that might not exist since exception with doing: `file_to_write = open(target_file, 'w')` is being handled by at least last `except Exception as e` block, but then `finally` is run too.

Since exception happened as a result of not being able to `open` target file, you do not have anything assigned to `file_to_write` and that variable doesn't exist after exception is handled. That is why `finally` block crashes.

Comment: I have ran some test, and it looks like this is it. Thanks.